# How do I count the words in a part of a file, without leaving vim?

Tags: external-command, counting

I have a file full of text (say Markdown or LaTeX). I would like to count the number of words in a part of this file.

I know I can do <kbd>:! wc -w %</kbd> to run wc -w on the current buffer. And I know that I can yank the section of interest into a named register. I'm guessing there's a way to send a named register to the operating system for use in a command or pipe, but I haven't been able to find one. Or is there a better way to count the words in a register?

My use case is that I do a lot of non-programming writing (notes, thesis, etc) in vim, and I would like to count how many words I've added to a given section of the file in the middle of an editing session.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>CTRL+g</kbd>, which will give you:

```
Col 1 of 118-121; Line 1 of 5; Word 1 of 142; Byte 1 of 678
```

You can also use this from visual mode, if you want to get the word count for just the selection, which is especially useful combined with text objects such as [`ip`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#ip). (e.g. you can use `vipg<C-g>` to get the word count of the current paragraph).

See: [`:help word-count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#word-count) and [`:help text-objects`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects).

---

The above option is probably better, but you can also use `wc` utility to count the number of words in a section. Aside from the `:! wc -w %` form you use, you can also use`:%!wc -w`. This will filter a motion to a shell tool (in this case `%`, the entire buffer), but you can also use other ranges (such as `:1,5!wc -w` for the first 5 lines, `!,+5!wc -w` for the current and next 5 lines, etc.). You can also select text in visual mode, and type `:!wc -w` to filter your selection.

Note that this will replace the motion with the output of the shell tool, but you can `u` to undo this.

See [`:help :range!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Arange%21), 
[`:help range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%7Baddress%7D), and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3232/51) where I give more examples of ranges.

Comment: I had found something like this while searching, but missed that the first g is part of the counting command, not a location specifier. This solution makes sense now. I apparently should also read up on Visual mode; I don't use it often enough.

Comment: I had no idea that you could use `g<C-g>` that way.  Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways this can be accomplished, the pure vimscript way and the `wc` way.

#### The pure vim way

You can use the search and replace command to do this.  For example:

```
:%s/\<\w\{-}\>//gn
```

What this does is instead of replacing a given pattern with something, it just counts the occurrences of the pattern.  This is because of the `n` flag.  To count the words in a specific section (in this case lines 5 through 15), you could do something like this:

```
:5,15s/\<\w\{-}\>//gn
```

This removes the need to yank the contents of a selection into a register.  To see more possibilities for what can be put in place of `5-15`, read the help topic for `cmdline-ranges`.  If you want to do this often, it is probably good to create a mapping (or command) for it.  Also, if you have `hlsearch` enabled, you might want to run `:nohlsearch` afterwards to clear the highlighting.

#### The `wc` way

The same thing can be accomplished with `wc`.   In the same way you can use `cmdline-ranges` to select the area with the `:s` command, you can use them with external commands.  For example:

```
:5,15!wc -w
```

This runs lines 5 through 15 through the `wc` command.  The downside to this is that it replaces that range of lines with the output of the command.  You can undo this change by pressing `u`.  Also note that the vimscript solution may not work with different languages, because `\w` does not match what would normally be word characters in other languages.  `wc` may do better at this than `\w`.  Also, here is a fancy command to make it faster to do this:

```
command -range=% -addr=lines WordCount execute '<count>!wc -w' | .y a | undo | echo @a
```

Note that this clobbers the `a` register.

#### Note

It appears that this can also be accomplished in visual mode with the `g<C-g>` key combination.  See Carpetsmoker's answer for an explanation of this.

Comment: These need a g along with the n in order to make them global (otherwise, they only match one word per line). The second one also needs an s at the beginning.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: Using `\w` sounds like a nice idea at first, but after testing it I found a number of problems. The biggest is that it won't match non-ascii characters, so a word like `über` is simply skipped (there was a [question about this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3726/51) yesterday). Also, a word like `e-mail` is counted as 2 words, since `-` is not in `\w` (using a `-` is somewhat uncommon in English, but very common in Dutch for example). There may be other characters which are ignored in this fashion, which brings us to my last point: conventions as to what is considered a "word" may differ ...

Comment: ... in various languages, and "proper" tools like `wc` may pick up on the locale (I don't know if GNU `wc` actually deals with this by the way, GNU tools are not well known for their excellent unicode support).

Comment: That is interesting.  I might add that as a plus to the `wc` solution.

Comment: At least on my system (cygwin, in the US), the vimscript method gave me the same result as running wc from from the command line. The file I tested it on has a few hyphenated words, and no non-ascii characters. Being off by a couple of words is close enough for my immediate purposes, but that's a good gotcha to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For words use:

```
:.,+4 s/\i\+/&/gn
```

`.` denotes the current line.

Also I put the following in my .vimrc file:

```
:cabbrev zzcc   s/./&/gn

:cabbrev zzcw   s/\i\+/&/g
```

I can type:

```
:.,+6 zzcw
```

and the `zzcw` will expand to `s/\i\+/&/g`

The `zzcw` is just an odd name that won't
match anything (for me).

A side effect is the entire file is selected
and highlighted.

I wanted to be able to type multi-line tweets 
in a file, make sure there weren't too many 
characters, and paste the tweet in twitter.