# Count only words for which Spell is enabled?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, spell-checking, counting

I want to count the words in my buffers, but for TeX files, for instance, a lot of words (e.g., commands) shouldn't be counted. I'm aware that there are scripts that do this specifically for LaTeX, but I find them pretty inconvenient and they don't even work that well.

On the other hand, whoever wrote the syntax files for TeX already did a great job at tagging which words should be counted: the words for which Spell is enabled. Besides, using a method like this would be useful for every filetype, potentially ignoring comments and so on. And if you want to ignore more words you could just change it in your `after/syntax` files.

I couldn't figure out a way to do it, though. So, any ideas on how I could count only the words for which Spell is enabled?

I think [this method](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3742/7642) (`:%s/\<\w\{-}\>//gn`) of counting the words looks like a good start, but we'd have to skip some words depending on their highlighting group.

Comment: I'd run some TeX to text converter in the shell, then count *those* words. http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-toascii.html

Comment: @VanLaser Ah, yes, like I said, there are scripts that do that already, and Vimtex even uses one of them… I just think this method would be better if there were a way to do it. And I think it would be easier to keep the count up to date and show the results in the status line for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I trust the syntax that much :) This thread may help (you or somebody that wants to test his/her skills): http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/how-to-search-for-pattern-in-certain-syntax-regions

Comment: @VanLaser Interesting, thanks! Maybe the syntax isn't that trustworthy out of the box, but I've been playing with it and tweaking my `after/syntax` file and I think it would work pretty well at this point. :)

Comment: Just for reference (and not what you want), I was reading a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/54dsuz/latex_tips_and_tricks/) today - it mentions `texcount` (included with TeXLive etc.); just did a check and saw that it's the same one used by the vimtex plugin (which you mentioned above).

Comment: @VanLaser I wrote that post, actually, haha! After reading your comment I decided to take another look at `texcount` and came up with that. Then I thought "cool, I'll share this on reddit". I'm still curious about this approach, though.

Comment: LOL, I should've looked at the poster's nickname at least once ... :) Well, since you seem to like dabbling with Vim syntax, perhaps we'll see an answer from you, later on ;)